# gnuplot: plot multiple datasets from file only if all data is present

Tags: gnuplot

to make the thing clear:

i have data that looks like this:

```
0,  , ,1,2
1,  , ,2,3
2, 1, ,4,5
3, 1, ,4,6
4, 1,1,4,7
5, 1,2,5,8
6, 1,4,6,7
```

multiple columns with missing values (only at the begin of the file).
now i want to plot, column 2,3,and 5
but the plots should start at the point where all the sets i want to plot have data.

so if my xrange is [0:10]
only from 4:6 should be plotted if i plot 2,3,5.
If i plot 2,4,5 then from 2:6 should be plotted.
is there some possibility to test if a value exists?

i allready tried something like

```
plot \
"file.txt" using 1:($2 + ($3*0) + ($5*0)) with lines, \
"file.txt" using 1:($3 + ($2*0) + ($5*0)) with lines, \
"file.txt" using 1:($5 + ($3*0) + ($2*0)) with lines, \
```

because i hoped if the data of one element to use is not present then gnuplot will ignore the whole line.

Somebody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahhh -  i misinterpreted my output.

Now if i test the whole thing on the minimal example i posted above, my solution seems to work.

i now created some check function dummys, to made things a bit nicer.

```
check2(x1, x2) = 0
check3(x1, x2, x3) = 0
check4(x1, x2, x3, x4) = 0
check5(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) = 0
check6(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6) = 0
check7(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7) = 0
check8(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) = 0

plot \
"file.txt" using 1:($2 + check3($2, $3, $5)) with lines, \
"file.txt" using 1:($3 + check3($2, $3, $5)) with lines, \
"file.txt" using 1:($5 + check3($2, $3, $5)) with lines, \
```

however if somebody knows a better way, please share your knowledge.

thank you

#### edit:

in combination with macros that Christoph suggested in the other answer the whole thing is more compact:

```
set macro
check3(x1, x2, x3) = 0
AllOrNothing = "check3($2, $3, $5)"
plot \
"file.txt" using 1:($2 + @AllOrNothing ) with lines, \
"file.txt" using 1:($3 + @AllOrNothing ) with lines, \
"file.txt" using 1:($5 + @AllOrNothing ) with lines
```

Comment: I like your solution. I didn't know, that the result of a function depends on the validity of its arguments although they are not used.

Comment: @Christoph it seems that gnuplot only evaulates expressions if all used inputs are valid else it ignores the complete dataset and does not plot a point

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can use the `valid` function to check if a column contains valid data. This returns `1` if the data is valid, `0` otherwise. So a possible `plot` command looks like this:

```
plot 'file.txt' using 1:(valid(2)+valid(4)+valid(5) == 3 ? $2 : 1/0),\
...
```

Following is a variant, where the columns to use are defined in a string `cols`. The `valid` check is constructed dynamically and invokes as macro later in the using statement.

```
set datafile separator ','
set style data lines
set macros

cols = "2 4 5"
col_cnt = words(cols)
col_valid = ""
do for [i in cols] {
    col_valid = col_valid . sprintf("valid(%s)+", i)
}
col_valid = col_valid . '0 != col_cnt ? 1/0'

set offsets 0,0,1,1
plot 'file.txt' using 1:(@col_valid : $2) t 'col 2',\
     '' using 1:(@col_valid : $4) t 'col 4',\
     '' using 1:(@col_valid : $5) t 'col 5'
```

You could of course also include looping over the `cols` values. I have skipped that part so retain some readability `;)`.

EDIT: Improved the script according to @vlad_tepesch's comment.

Comment: i am not sure if i understand the plot command.  i never saw the @ before what does it do with the col_str variable? i also could not find it in the help.  Can you explain the lower variant?

Comment: @vlad_tepesch The @ treats a variable as macro, i.e. `@var` is replaced by the string contained in `var` and then evaluated. This behaviour must be enabled with `set macros`. An easy example would be `set macros; var = 'sin(x)'; plot @var`. However, I don't know if there is a difference between `@var` and `eval(var)`.

Comment: thank you, i think i got it, but code it should be possible to put more into the macro: instead of `col_str = col_str . '0'` `col_str = col_str . '0 != col_cnt? 1/0  '` may be possible so that the plot looks like `using 1:(@col_str : $4 ) ` now it should get a better name

Comment: Now that I think of it, of course there is a difference between `eval` and `@var`: macros are only for substitutions to build up complex/dynamic commands and `eval` evaluates the given string as if it was a full line in a script (sort of...).

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Yes, that is definitely better. If you don't mind, I would put this enhancement in my answer, because it makes it much more readable.

Comment: of course put it in - why dose the @Christoph at beginning not work

Comment: @vlad_tepesch I think it is removed, because the answerer is notified in any case about comments to his answer.